# Vue - Push for nested object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a form that consists of nested objects (see the object structure below) using Vue and The Quasar Framework. I want to add questions and for each question, as many answers as possible.(Note: I have edited the question with the full file.)
I am having issues when I click on the add button. I tried to add a question and it does allow me to create another question (q1)and more by clicking on the initial question (q0). However, if I want to create a question by clicking on (q1), I get the following errors in the console.

```
[Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "click": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'questions' of undefined"
```

I also tried the following with
this.forms[index].questions[index].answerChoices.push
I get the following warning:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "click": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'questions' of undefined"
```

I've looked at various solutions on StackOverflow and other sites. I have tried to implement them but none have worked so far. 
Any suggestions please?

```
    <template>
  <q-page>
          <q-card class="bg-cyan-2 q-ma-xl">
            <q-card-main>
            <div v-for="form in forms" :key="form.id">
              <q-field class="q-mb-sm" label="Form Title: " helper="Please enter the title of the question.">
                <q-input v-model="form.name" type="text" clearable />
              </q-field>
              <q-card-separator class="q-mb-md q-mt-xl"/>
           <div v-for="(question, index) in form.questions" :key="question.id">
            <q-btn class="q-mb-md" round size="sm" color="amber" icon="add" @click="addRowQuestions(index)" />
            <q-field class="q-mb-sm" label="Question Title: " >
              <q-input v-model="question.text" />
            </q-field>
            <q-card-separator class="q-mb-md q-mt-xl"/>
              <div v-for="(answerChoice, index) in question.answerChoices" :key="answerChoice.id">
                <q-btn class="q-mb-md" round size="sm" color="green" icon="add" @click="addAnswers(index)" />
                <q-field class="q-mb-sm" label="Answer ID: ">
                  <q-input v-model="answerChoice.answerId" type="number" clearable />
                </q-field>
            <q-card-separator class="q-mb-md q-mt-xl"/>
              </div>
           </div>
           </div>
            </q-card-main>
          </q-card>
  </q-page>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      forms: [
        {
          name: '',
          questions: [
            {
              text: '',
              answerChoices: [
                {
                  answerId: ''
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addRowQuestions (index) {
      this.forms[index].questions.push({
        text: '',
        answerChoices: []
      })
    },
    addAnswers (index) {
      this.forms[index].questions[index].answerChoices.push({
        answerId: ''
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Questions in the form of "why does x not work" or "why do I get error y" need to contain a [mcve] that allows us to reproduce the problem. In your case we need an actual vue file as you currently just have some random snippets of html and javascript, but not enough to follow the flow of your component.

Comment: I've reedited the question according to comments by @summurai8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to get this to work. My modified working code is below for anyone interested. Note that I have added 2 extra buttons to allow the removal of questions and answers.

```
<div v-for="(form, fIndex) in forms" :key="form.id">
          <q-field class="q-mb-sm" label="Form Title: " helper="Please enter the title of the form.">
            <q-input v-model="form.name" type="text" clearable />
          </q-field>
          <q-card-separator class="q-mb-md q-mt-xl"/>
       <div v-for="(question, qIndex) in form.questions" :key="question.id">
        <q-btn class="q-mb-md" round size="sm" color="amber" icon="add" @click="addRowQuestions(fIndex)" />
        <q-btn class="vertical-top" v-show="qIndex !==0" round size="sm" color="blue" icon="remove" @click="remRowQs(fIndex)" />
        <q-field class="q-mb-sm" label="Question Title: " >
          <q-input v-model="question.text" />
        </q-field>
        <q-card-separator class="q-mb-md q-mt-xl"/>
          <div v-for="(answerChoice, aIndex) in question.answerChoices" :key="answerChoice.id">
            <q-btn class="q-mb-md" round size="sm" color="green" icon="add" @click="addAnswers(fIndex, qIndex)" />
            <q-btn class="vertical-top" v-show="aIndex !==0" round size="sm" color="negative" icon="remove" @click="remRowAns(fIndex, qIndex)" />
            <q-field class="q-mb-sm" label="Answer ID: ">
              <q-input v-model="answerChoice.answerId" type="number" clearable />
            </q-field>
        <q-card-separator class="q-mb-md q-mt-xl"/>
          </div>
       </div>
       </div>

    methods: {
    addRowQuestions (fIndex) {
      this.forms[fIndex].questions.push({
        qtext: '',
        answerChoices: [
          {
            answerId: ''
          }
        ]
      })
    },
    addAnswers (fIndex, qIndex) {
      this.forms[fIndex].questions[qIndex].answerChoices.push({
        answerId: ''
      })
    },
    remRowQs (fIndex) {
      this.forms[fIndex].questions.splice(fIndex, 1)
    },
    remRowAns (fIndex, qIndex) {
      this.forms[fIndex].questions[qIndex].answerChoices.splice(qIndex, 1)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not creating a new form, just a new question in forms[0] when you are adding a question. So there is no 'this.forms[1]' and thus this.forms[1].questions is undefined.

Comment: Thanks. I saw your message after this issue has been solved. I had to use the respective indexes to solve this.